# Confused between "If I had had more time" and "If I had more time"

Tags: conditional-constructions, understanding

1. If I had had more time, I would have solved the puzzle. [Past unreal/Past+Past]
   (I did not have more time so I did not solve the puzzle.)
2. If I had more time, I would have solved the puzzle. [Mixed conditionals/Present+Past]
   (I do not have more time so I did not solve the puzzle.)

I want to know when & which context these sentences are used in conversation. Do the both sentences have same meaning? Can we use them interchangeably?

Comment: The first one is correct. With the second one, do you think it makes sense to say that if you had more time (present time), you would have solved the puzzle (past time)?

Comment: @ BillJ  Many books have mentioned such types of sentences while explaining Mixed conditionals. some More Examples: 1] If I were rich, I would have bought that Ferrari we saw yesterday. (BUT I AM NOT CURRENTLY RICH AND THAT IS WHY I DIDN'T BUY THE FERRARI
YESTERDAY.) 2] If Sam spoke Russian, he would have translated the letter for you.(BUT SAM DOESN'T SPEAK RUSSIAN AND THAT IS WHY HE DIDN'T TRANSLATE THE
LETTER.) 3] If I were smarter, I would have graduated from Stanford.
(But I am not smarter and therefore I didn't graduate from Stanford)

Comment: I think we’d normally expect #2 to be: _If I had more time, I would solve the puzzle_.

Comment: If you never have a lot of time (at any time), then you can say 2. (or 1). But if it's a matter of not having enough time only at some specific time in the past, then 1) would be appropriate; we understand that you didn't have enough time then, but you may have now.

Comment: @J.R. Exactly. This is very SIMPLE: If I had had more time, I would have solved [etc.] VERSUS If I had more time, I would solve. 2) is agrammatical. Simple past + past conditional is simply not expressing the idea correctly.

Comment: @Lambie - Simple to us, yes, but understandably confusing for the beginner.

Comment: @J.R. The explanations should be simple too. I didn't see a simple explanation. If one doesn't know the grammar, one can't explain it.

Comment: I don't agree with Lambie or JR. If the situation expressed in the protasis is understood as permanent (or relatively so), i.e. it relates to past and present time and is ongoing, then it is possible to use a modal preterite like "had", while using the perfect in the apodosis. Examples like _If Ed spoke French, he would have translated the letter for you_ and _If I enjoyed Shakespeare, I would have gone with you_ are fine. In the OP's example, if the lack of time is of a permanent nature, then example 2. is possible.

Comment: @BillJ Indeed, and, additionally,  just purely from a grammatical point of view, the protasis in 2) need not be considered to be a modally remote construction. [Let's say the speaker cannot remember whether he had more time or not or whether he finished the puzzle or not]

Comment: Not sure that having time can be a permanent thing.

Comment: It's common in casual usage to use simple past instead of past perfect, particularly where the sequence of events is either obvious or doesn't matter. 2 sounds fine to me, even if it's describing a past situation (not having time in the past).

Answer (score 1):

> If I had had more time, I would have solved the puzzle.

This structure is used for a past that is disconnected in some way from the present.  The disconnection might be as ordinary as a night's sleep, or as momentous as, e.g., being attacked by home-invaders: "If I had had more time, I could have found my gun and held them off.  But I didn't have more time, and so here we are, out in the street in our pyjamas!".

> If I had more time, I would have solved the puzzle.

Here the lack-of-time period is in the *immediate* past, still psychologically connected to the present.  "If I had more time, I would have finished painting the room, but I had to stop so that I could shower and catch my flight to Boston."  The "time" in this case extends toward or even into the present as a sort of phantom in which something could have been done/completed but had to be abandoned for some more important activity.